# Are questions about leagues on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

After asking [What does map ban mean in StarCraft 1 leagues?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/344378/95533), I visit [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and realize that this type of question isn't specifically addressed. So are we for or against it?

FWIW we have the [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming) tag.

Comment: FYI we have a competitive gaming tag https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming so I've proposed an edit to add this tag (also gave you an answer based on our clarification in comments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is covered under 'game mechanics and terminology', so it is on-topic here.

Comment: should it be made explicit? I thought that point is only about games themselves, not leagues.